# Cloud Container Builder, ZIP does not support timestamps before 1980

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-container-registry, google-container-builder

I'm trying the following tutorial.

[Automatic serverless deployments with Cloud Source Repositories and Container Builder](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2018/03/automatic-serverless-deployments-with-Cloud-Source-Repositories-and-Container-Builder.html)

But I got the error below.

```
$ gcloud container builds submit --config deploy.yaml .

BUILD
Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.functions.deploy) Error creating a ZIP archive with the source code for directory .: ZIP does not support timestamps before 1980
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud" failed: exit status 1
```

I'm now trying to solve it. Do you have any idea? My gcloud is the latest version.

```
$ gcloud -v
Google Cloud SDK 193.0.0
app-engine-go 
app-engine-python 1.9.67
beta 2017.09.15
bq 2.0.30
core 2018.03.09
gsutil 4.28
```

Sample google cloud function code on the tutorial.

```
#index.js
exports.f = function(req, res) {
  res.send("hello, gcf!");
};

#deploy.yaml
steps:
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
  args:
  - beta
  - functions
  - deploy
  - --trigger-http
  - --source=.
  - --entry-point=f
  - hello-gcf # Function name

#deploying without Cloud Container Builder is fine.
gcloud beta functions deploy --trigger-http --source=. --entry-point=f hello-gcf
```

Comment: What files do you have in your source? (`ls -alh`)? Is the old file coming from the tutorial?

Comment: In my case this came from accidentally including the node modules directory in the upload to gcp after building a node.js cloud function locally for testing, I guess it is on a case by case basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Container Builder tars your source folder. Maybe something in your . directory has corrupted dates? That's why moving it to the source folder fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know the reason, I found a workaround.

```
(1) make src directory and move index.js into it.

├── deploy.yaml
└── src
    └── index.js

(2) deploy via Cloud Container Builder.

$ gcloud container builds submit --config deploy.yaml ./src
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue now. I could not solve it but at least I found out where it comes from.
When you locally submit your build there is a tar created and uploaded to a bucket. In this tar the folders are created at 01.01.1970:

```
16777221 8683238 drwxr-xr-x 8 user staff 0 256 "Jan  1 01:00:00 1970" "Jan  1 01:00:00 1970" "May 15 12:42:04 2019" "Jan  1 01:00:00 1970" 4096 0 0 test
```

This issue only occurs locally. If you have a github build trigger it works

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across the same issue using Cloud Build (the successor to Container Builder).

What helped was adding a step to list all the files/folders in the Cloud Build environment (default directory is `/workspace`) to identify the problematic file/folder. You can do this by overriding the `gcloud` container's entrypoint to execute the `ls` command.

```
steps
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
    entrypoint: "ls"
    args: ["-la", "/workspace"]
```